# django how to get old value and new value in pre_save fucntion

Tags: django, django-orm, django-signals

Imagine I have a model called `A`, which has a field called `name`. How can I get previous value and new value in `pre_save` signal?

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=A)
def signal_product_manage_latest_version_id(
        sender, instance, update_fields=None, **kwargs):
    if 'name' in update_fields:
        print(instance.name)
```

Will the `name` be the old value or the new value when I call the following?

```
a = A.objects.create(name="John")
a.name = "Lee"
a.save()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#pre-save) `instance` The actual instance **being saved**.

You will get the *old instance* of **`A`** by explicitly calling it using **`.get()`** method as,

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=A)
def signal_product_manage_latest_version_id(sender, instance, update_fields=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        old_instance = A.objects.get(id=instance.id)
    except A.DoesNotExist:  # to handle initial object creation
        return None  # just exiting from signal
    # your code to with 'old_instance'
```

Comment: Also keep in mind, if object saved first time, it's old version isn't presented in database, so `objects.get` will cause exception.

Comment: @zen11625 Thanks for the info. I've updated the answer to handling that situation